# Read last line in sys.stdin

Tags: python-3.x, stdin

For a coding problem, I have to read data using sys.stdin. However, the method I am using is a for loop iterating over sys.stdin and it fails as the input does not include newlines after a test case is inputted.

Sample Input:

```
10 20
#################---
##-###############--
#---################
##-#################
########---#########
#######-----########
########---#########
##################--
#################---
##################-#
3 10
#-########
----------
#-########
```

Code used to read input:

```
grids = []
for line in stdin:
    if line == "\n":
        break
    m, n = map(int, line.split())
    grid = []
    for row in range(m):
        r = list(stdin.readline().strip())
        print("ROW:",r)
        grid.append(r)
    grids.append(grid)
return grids
```

Current Output:

```
ROW: ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '-', '-', '-']
ROW: ['#', '#', '-', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '-', '-']
ROW: ['#', '-', '-', '-', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
ROW: ['#', '#', '-', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
ROW: ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '-', '-', '-', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
ROW: ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
ROW: ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '-', '-', '-', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
ROW: ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '-', '-']
ROW: ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '-', '-', '-']
ROW: ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '-', '#']
ROW: ['#', '-', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
ROW: ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
```

Desired Output:

```
ROW: ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '-', '-', '-']
ROW: ['#', '#', '-', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '-', '-']
ROW: ['#', '-', '-', '-', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
ROW: ['#', '#', '-', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
ROW: ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '-', '-', '-', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
ROW: ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
ROW: ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '-', '-', '-', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
ROW: ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '-', '-']
ROW: ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '-', '-', '-']
ROW: ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '-', '#']
ROW: ['#', '-', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
ROW: ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
ROW: ['#', '-', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
```

As can be seen, the last line is not printed and is therefore not read, as newline is not included in input. Therefore, is there any way for me to read the last line? Please advise.

I am using Pycharm Community Edition 2017.

Edit:

This issue was solved when I ran it within the IDLE shell, I suspect the version of Pycharm used had some bugs, leading to this error. Anyways, thanks for the help.

Comment: Does the last line of your input contain "\n" (0x0a)? 
It's not possible to tell from this post.

Comment: @gbajson the there is no newline at the start or end, but newlines are used to separate the lines as shown in the sample.

Comment: I don't think the formatting is okay in the code you have posted. Seems everything is part of the for loop when it clearly shouldn't be

Comment: *"Is there such a function on stdin?"* - why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your input contains "\n" at the end.

Snippet from python documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html?highlight=readline

> f.readline() reads a single line from the file; a newline character
>   (\n) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last
>   line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline. **This makes
>   the return value unambiguous**

Comment: But the problem is that there is no "\n" at the end of the file, therefore last line cannot be read, and the question here is how is it possible to read it

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem (https://pastebin.com/51aqaQgy). I prepared the file without "\n" and your code (with `stdin = sys.stdin` at the beginning) works just fine. How exactly do you provide input data to your script?
I am using linux and python 3.6.